# python3系で複数回文字列置換を行いたい

Tags: python, 正規表現, python3

python3系で対象となる文字列に含まれるパターンすべてを置換するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
例としましては

[[wiki.cgi?=PAGE|PAGE]]を参照するには[[wiki.cgi?=TITLE|TITLE]]にアクセスしてください
↓
[[PAGE]]を参照するには[[TITLE]]にアクセスしてください

のようにしたいと考えております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reモジュールの[sub関数](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/re.html#re.sub)、もしくは[regex.sub](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/re.html#re.regex.sub)が使えます。

例:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.sub(r'\[\[wiki\.cgi\?=([A-Z]+)\|\1\]\]', r'[[\1]]', '[[wiki.cgi?=PAGE
   ...: |PAGE]]を参照するには[[wiki.cgi?=TITLE|TITLE]]にアクセスしてください')
Out[2]: '[[PAGE]]を参照するには[[TITLE]]にアクセスしてください'
```

Comment: わかりづらくて申し訳ないですが、例では文章の一部のみを提示しております。
実際の文章は[[wiki.cgi?=PAGE|PAGE]]のようなタグが随所に見られ、そのすべてのタグに対して
「wiki.cgi?=」の部分を切り取る
「=」のあとに続く文字列を取り出す
2つのブラケットで抽出した文字列を囲む
ということをしたいと考えております。

re.subを利用した文字列置換の場合ですと、複数行の置換や一行に複数のパターンが
含まれている場合にどうすればよいかわかりますでしょうか？

Comment: @codez よく分からないので、例のコードで上手く行かない入力（と理想の出力）を挙げて頂けますか？

Comment: letrec様
私の勘違いでした。提示して頂いたコードで問題なく動作いたしました。